# MAX(dates) returning slowly in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have a question about max(dates) in Sybase ASE.
I am working with a table that has millions of rows, but at this point I am only looking for the latest date the item was sold.

If I run this:

```
select * 
from DailySales.dbo.DailySales   
where ItemID = 558
```

I get 60 records in 190ms, with the latest date being a little over three years ago, but if I run:

```
select max(SalesDate) 
from DailySales.dbo.DailySales   
where ItemID = 558
```

It runs for a very long time, (I stopped at 4 minutes).
Newer dates get returned instantaneously.

What is happening here?

I have attached a picture of the indexes:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest a) providing the query plans for the fast and slow queries and b) providing the details of the indexes (eg, index name, column(s) in the index, non/clustered, unique, etc); it sounds like the optimizer isn't able to find an index it can use to 'speed up' your query (alternatively you may have a good index but out-of-date stats ... hard to tell without index and query plan details)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular query you need to *seek* by `ItemID` and *walk* (although a single step) by `SalesDate`. With this in mind, the index would be:

```
create index ix1 on DailySales.dbo.DailySales (ItemID, SalesDate)
```

Try the query after you create this index.